# Vertical and horizontal centering with flexbox in Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm centering a div in vertical and horizontal, but in Safari don't work.

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Safari**

[image]

See an example:
http://ux-heuristics.webflow.io/

Comment: I thought Safari was basicly compliant for flexbox now, hmm try it with `-webkit-` prefixes.

Comment: I see no flexbox parameters for any of these elements in the code on the website you posted the link for (?). Also the `a` tag containing the circle with the arrow isn't inside the container your screenshot shows.

Answer (score 1):

I just inspected the source of your website. Your markup is wrong. You need to place each
`<a class="play-btn w-inline-block" href="#"></a>` link inside its corresponding
`<div class="visibility-content"></div>`.

Than add this to your CSS

```css
.visibility-content {
  position: relative;
}
.visibility-content .play-btn{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
       -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
          transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

The markup of each section should look like this:

```html
<div class="section-content">
    <h2 class="section-title">Visibility of system status</h2>
    <p class="section-description">The system should always keep users informed 
    about what is going on, through appropriate feedback within reasonable time.</p>
    <div class="visibility-content">
        <a class="play-btn w-inline-block" href="#"></a>
        <div class="visibility-content-top"></div>
        <div class="visibility-bottom"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is all.

---

Initial answer:

If it must work in all versions of Safari, you'll need to revert to the box-model:

```css
body { margin: 0;} /* You don't need this rule, it's just for SO snippet */

parent {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
child {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3rem;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<parent>
  <child>I am centered in all browsers. Yay!</child>
</parent>
<parent>
  <child>I am centered in all browsers. Yay!</child>
</parent>
<parent>
  <child>I am centered in all browsers. Yay!</child>
</parent>
<parent>
  <child>I am centered in all browsers. Yay!</child>
</parent>
<parent>
  <child>I am centered in all browsers. Yay!</child>
</parent>
```

The only problem with it is you need to give `<parent>` a `min-height`. My personal preference is `100vh` (viewport height).

Comment: This solution don't work in this case, because I have another div in other locations and your solution merge all div in the same position.

Comment: I just added more elements without touching the CSS. Take a look.

Comment: The parent div I need user flexbox. If i remove this feature works fine.

Comment: I prefixed my answer with a practical solution applicable to your case. Feel free to assume it won't work and not even try it.

Comment: Your solution work with the two items? I put your code and works only for the first item.

Comment: Did you place all the links inside their divs?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I create a JSFiddle to test because I couldnt run the code here.

Comment: It's ok. Additionally you might want to add this to your CSS: `body>.visibility {min-height: 550px;}.visibility-content{overflow: auto;}`. Take care.

Comment: Thanks for attention. Works fine to me now!